# How to call below javascript in a function so that a it can be call using a button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
const address = 'rfginNsDt73fZtzp858dT6Y6U67Y1QB7GV';
const secret = 'sdfdfsdfsdfdsfdsfsdffd';

var api = new ripple.RippleAPI({
  server: 'wss://s1.ripple.com/'
});
const instructions = {
  maxLedgerVersionOffset: 5
};

var addrs = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>');
var dt = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox2.ClientID %>');
var amnt = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox3.ClientID %>');
const payment = {
  source: {
    address: address,
    maxAmount: {
      value: '0.01',
      currency: 'XRP'
    }
  },
  destination: {
    address: 'rpkoLuBqyn5svRnAfiHf7Vs3o2emVBmyQb',
    tag: 12321,
    amount: {
      value: '1',
      currency: 'XRP'
    }
  }
};

function quit(message) {
  console.log(message);
  process.exit(0);
}


function fail(message) {
  console.error(message);
  process.exit(1);
}

api.connect().then(() => {
  console.log('Connected...');
  return api.preparePayment(address, payment, instructions).then(prepared => {
    console.log('Payment transaction prepared...');
    const {
      signedTransaction
    } = api.sign(prepared.txJSON, secret);
    console.log('Payment transaction signed...');
    api.submit(signedTransaction).then(quit, fail);
  });

}).catch(fail);
```

I am calling this javaScript in Asp.net and i want to call it using an asp.net button using onClientClick() but for that i need to call this javascript in a function but it is not running when putting this whole script in a function abc()
{} and i have take input ``values of three text boxes TextBox1,2,3 from asp.net and json value is in single quotes dont know how to implement it in single quote and wheater i am getting currect value or not.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your text is just word salad. Can you possibly form real sentences and use some punctuation?

Comment: how to call this javascript in a function so that i can call it using a button